# How do I add an external calendar like Cozi in Outlook for Mac?

Tags: outlook

I am using Outlook for Mac, which I assume is Outlook for Mac 2016 because the version is 16.28.  I have looked online at the instructions on how to import an online calendar like Cozi, however, the instructions are for the PC version of Outlook.  The Outlook for Mac version does not include the "import calendar" capability.  Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get around this issue, you have to go to the web-based version of Outlook which is found at outlook.office365.com.  View the calendar and you will see the option to "import a calendar."  For Cozi, I followed the instructions on their site to share a calendar and copied the URL.  I then pasted it into the web-based version of Outlook.

Then, go back into your Outlook for Mac program and you should see the imported calendar.  You may have to check the box next to it to get it to display.

NOTE:  When I first displayed the calendar, it showed them side-by-side.  Goto View->Overlay if you want to see them all in one view.